# Why can't space become fuel for spaceships?

Tags: rocket-science, hydrogen, estimation, propulsion, interstellar-matter

I read somewhere that space is constitued mostly of hydrogen.

So why can't space and its constituants (not only hydrogen) serve as fuel for future spaceships?

The dreamer I am simply imagine a spaceship with a very large open mouth at its front in order to harvest the particles (fuel) necessary for its propulsion system.

It wouldn't need to carry any kind of fuel, right?

Why isn't it conceptually feasible? (never heard of it)

Comment: It's true that matter consists overwhelmingly of hydrogen, but matter is pretty sparse in outer space---it's largely concentrated in structures like stars and planets. The average density of the universe might be around one hydrogen atom per cubic meter. That's certainly not enough to fuel a moving spaceship.

Comment: You should read about [Bussard ramjet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet) idea.

Comment: @OON - You beat me to it.

Comment: Nebula contain hydrogen, dust, & a lot of other things.  You could probably collect it there, but if you ran out as you moved through space and you couldn't reach another nebula, you would have to find another source of H.  Given that suns are muy caliente (very hot) & very massive--it's not likely that you could tap them for H.

Comment: Something that is everywhere are photons. That's probably where you should be looking.

Comment: @user35736 Thank you very much for the clarification. But hydrogen was just an example. The question isn't solely about hydrogen. I'm going to edit my question in order to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @BillAlsept Thanks. Apart from the conventional solar panels, are there more effective ways of collecting energy from photons? (in costly lab settings for example).

Comment: @DIYser The question is about a fuel that would be available anywhere in space and not only in specific areas. Just like a submarine that would use sea water for its fuel (why doesn't it exist either BTW?)

Comment: @FrankinJapan who knows maybe in the future there will be powerful engines or technology that will required minimal photons.

Comment: @FranckInJapan - re:  "like a submarine that would use sea water for its fuel (why doesn't it exist either BTW?)"  It does exist, btw.  It didn't exist until this century because it takes energy to convert water into H2 & O.  In the ocean, electrolysis is a less a efficient system than nuclear energy systems because the energy to enrich the nuclear fuel was used on land.

Comment: @DIYser You should look up the density of the densest nebulae in the universe, and compare that number to the best vacuum ever made in a lab on Earth ;)

Comment: @Chris White - Exactly what point are you trying to make about whatever that difference is?

Answer (score 3):

"The question is a fuel that would be available anywhere in space and not only in specific areas.":
The problem is that the density in the interstellar medium is extremely weak, less than the best void we can do on Earth. So you will need a long trip just to collect 1 liter at atmospheric pressure. Besides, you would need energy to collect and transform it into a usable form.

"like a submarine that would use seawater for its fuel (why doesn't it exist either BTW?)" : simply because water is not a combustible. If you want to extract it's hydrogen you need a huge amount of energy. If you want to extract some combustible dissolved in water then as for space you have the problem on little amount and energy of transform.

Nothing is for free in the universe!

Answer (score 2):

The only fuel we know of that is available anywhere in space is hydrogen. Unfortunately, there are 2 major stumbling blocks that prevent us from using it for propulsion.

1. It is extremely sparse. The vacuum of space is a lot better than the best we can produce on earth. There's only about 1 atom per $cm^3$. On earth there are of the order of $10^{18}$ atoms (not hydrogen but mostly Nitrogen and Oxygen) per $cm^3$. Quite a difference! However, there are ideas, like the [Bussard Ramjet](http://Bussard%20Ramjet) mentioned in @OON's comment, that let us collect these minute quantities of hydrogen, and use them.
2. There are only negligible quantities of oxygen in space so, even if we can collect the H & O, burning them generates virtually no power. The only way to use the hydrogen for propulsion is in a fusion reactor. That will produce a lot more power from the same hydrogen than burning will. Unfortunately, at present we have not yet made a fusion reactor on earth, let alone in space.

In conclusion, yes it is theoretically feasible to use the hydrogen in space for propulsion, there are many hurdles to overcome before we get there.

The answer given by @kpv talks about using vacuum energy. Unfortunately, at present, all indications are that vacuum energy, while it definitely exists, does not provide anywhere near enough energy to be useful.